# ESS: not start new R process for different file

Tags: ess, r

I often share an R process with multiple `.R` files. The default in ESS when I `ess-eval-line-invisibly-and-step` from a new file within a different R package I develop is to create a new R process. The current need is to allow this, then tell R to change the target process to my `*R:1*`, then kill this `*R:2*` that I didn't want it to create.

I think it's related to `ess-r-package-project`, `...-info`, or something within `ess-r-package-*`, but I can't seem to get it right.

Namely, these don't seem to change the behavior:

```
(setq ess-r-package-auto-activate nil)
(setq ess-r-package-mode nil)
(setq ess-r-package-auto-enable-namespaced-evaluation nil)
```

So I'd like to be able to either of the following:

- switch the target process before starting a new one
- do not automatically start a new process when in a new package directory

*Update*: emacs does not give me a complete choice of processes for a given buffer. Walk-through:

- open a file in one of my packages `pkg1`, start R into `*R:1:pkg1*`; sourcing lines (`ess-eval-line-invisibly-and-step`) sends code to this process, so far so good
- open a file in a different package `pkg2`, try to `ess-eval-line-invisibly-and-step` a line into the first process, instead starts `*R:2:pkg2*`
- try to switch the target process for `pkg2/file.R`, but `ess-switch-process` only offers `{ *R:2:pkg2* | *new* }`, does not show nor provides a way to select `*R:1:pkg1*`

Comment: Don't you get a question with a `Process to use: ` prompt about which process to use? That should come from `ess-force-buffer-current`, in which case you just give it the name of the existing process.

Comment: @NickD it does, but not a complete list. Even if it gave me a complete list of current R processes, I cannot pre-determine which process to send it to, since merely trying _something_ -- including `ess-switch-process` -- causes it to start a new one, at which point I would need to be able to see and select `*R:1:pkg1*` to be able to switch, but I cannot. I think this is a very recent bug, self-answering shortly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain that this really is the intended solution to the problem, but by reverting a portion of a recent commit ([88d611c](https://github.com/emacs-ess/ESS/commit/88d611c6833d521d0fbb2ef9c638bf6b3525a622)), I'm able to restore the original behavior:

The portion of the commit that I reverted is this:

```diff
diff --git a/lisp/ess-inf.el b/lisp/ess-inf.el
index 9ca3f455..aaff314c 100644
--- a/lisp/ess-inf.el
+++ b/lisp/ess-inf.el
@@ -828,6 +828,8 @@ to `ess-completing-read'."
                                                    'ess-dialect
                                                    (process-buffer (get-process (car lproc)))))
                                            (not (equal ess-local-process-name (car lproc)))
+                                           (equal (buffer-name (process-buffer (get-process (car lproc))))
+                                                  (funcall ess-gen-proc-buffer-name-function (car lproc)))
                                            (car lproc)))
                                     ess-process-name-list)
                             ;; append local only if running
```

By commenting out those two `+`-added lines, recompiling `ess-inf.el`, then reloading emacs, I'm able to restore the prior behavior. Namely, the walk-through from the (edited) question:

- open a file in one of my packages `pkg1`, start R into `*R:1:pkg1*`; sourcing lines (`ess-eval-line-invisibly-and-step`) sends code to this process, so far so good;
- open a file in a different package `pkg2`, and **now** doing `ess-eval-line-invisibly-and-step` on a line into the first process works; and
- calling `ess-switch-process` shows `{ *R:1:pkg1* | *R:2:pkg2* | *new* }`, as expected.

Again, I'm not certain that there isn't a preferred/intended/canonical way to get the pre-commit behavior I'm looking for. This is submitted as [ESS#1276](https://github.com/emacs-ess/ESS/issues/1276), perhaps the developers can shed light on it. *Edit*: patched with [d8472e0](https://github.com/emacs-ess/ESS/commit/d8472e00da8fde3224d4512641093b526601af39), not yet on melpa.